# There was an error running the query [Unknown column 'song.songTitle' in 'field list']

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

I am having an issue displaying a table from my database. Every time I run the page I get this error message:

> There was an error running the query [Unknown column 'song.songTitle' in 'field list']

[image]

Here is a `$sql` code block I am trying to pull the data from my table to my PHP form with:

Upper Switch Statement

```
code        case "songAlbum": {
            $tableFormat=SONG_ALBUM;
            $sql = "SELECT song.songTitle, song.url, album.albumTitle, album.albumPrice
                    FROM song
                    JOIN album
                    WHERE song.album_id = album.album_id
                    ORDER BY album.albumTitle";
            break;
        }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Show your table schema for `song`. It sounds like `songTitle` doesn't exist. Maybe it's `song_title`?

Comment: Yes, it's song_title, as shown in your schema. Make sure you also check the naming conventions of the album table, you may run into the same issue.

Comment: That worked!!!!! Thanks so much. I am still having an issue displaying the names of anything other than the video link in my php table. Any suggestions as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Not without the code, and that should probably be another question. But look at the array keys that you're trying to get from the table and make sure they match the table schema.

Answer (score 0):

Name of the column is `song_title`, not `songTitle`